# Django: run ".php" file via url

Tags: php, django

On the server with PHP we can put **myfile.php** in **myfolder** and then go to `https://mysite.ru/myfolder/myfile.php` to view the content.

Is it possible to do the same on a Django website?

I need to set up this script:
https://github.com/Surzhikov/Telegram-Site-Helper-2.0

Comment: you want to execute `php` file through `python` framework, are you sure it is good idea?

Comment: You want to use python to push telegram-site-helper-install.php onto a server?

Comment: Yes, but i am not sure is it possible or not

Comment: of course it is. you may need to use an SSH connection.

Comment: Okey, thanks! I will read about this

Comment: have at look at this http://www.paramiko.org/ http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html once you ssh in .... I would use sftp http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html